# How do I get Software Updater to update?

Tags: updates

I run Software Updater regularly, but lately it isn't actually updating my system.  I always get to the point where it says "The software on this computer is up to date", but I know that it's not because "uname -a" yields:

Linux intel-nuc2 3.13.0-49-generic #83-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 10 20:11:33 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

...and I believe it should now be up to 3.13.0-52-generic.  What have I been doing wrong lately?  I really want to stay current.

Comment: When you runs sudo apt-get upgrade, are there files in the section to be kept back? > The following packages have been kept back: linux-headers-generic Do you want the latest greatest distro version:
> do-release-upgrade

Comment: There are no files identified as kept back.  When I execute the command do-release-upgrade, it responds with "No new release found".

Comment: looks like you may be on the latest for your distro. With Linux Mint I am on : Linux Me 3.13.0-24-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 2 23:30:00 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: I think you should be at 3.13.0-51 see http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/linux-generic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just open a terminal and execute the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-generic
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

reboot!

In the future, just run the following commands to update the entire system:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: are these commands are just to update all installed packages

Comment: @PankajGautam Yes, if there is a new version available. This should also update the kernel if a new kernel is available. Also, some software may be uninstalled or removed as well.