# Ubuntu 16.04 - Software Updater does not show any updates

Tags: update-manager

It's been almost six days since Software Updater has not shown any updates for Ubuntu 16.04.

I have tried [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/622897/how-do-i-get-software-updater-to-update), but it didn't work. The Software Updater is showing this information:

[image]

The output from terminal after running `sudo apt-get update` is:

```
hirak@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get update
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release          
Hit:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease          
Ign:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nae-team/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease                            
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]                    
Get:7 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]                           
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease                 
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                              
Get:10 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [102 kB]                                       
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nae-team/ppa/ubuntu xenial Release                      
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nae-team/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages          
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nae-team/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages       
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nae-team/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nae-team/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_IN
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nae-team/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nae-team/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nae-team/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nae-team/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nae-team/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nae-team/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nae-team/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_IN
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nae-team/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nae-team/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nae-team/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons                                                    
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nae-team/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages                                                        
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nae-team/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages                                                         
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nae-team/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages                                                          
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nae-team/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_IN                                                     
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nae-team/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en                                                        
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nae-team/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata                                                 
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nae-team/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons                                                    
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nae-team/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages                                                        
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nae-team/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages                                                         
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nae-team/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages                                                          
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nae-team/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_IN                                                     
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nae-team/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en                                                        
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nae-team/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata                                                 
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nae-team/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons                                                    
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nae-team/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages                                                        
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nae-team/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages                                                         
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nae-team/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages                                                          
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nae-team/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_IN
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nae-team/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nae-team/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nae-team/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Err:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nae-team/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
404  Not Found
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nae-team/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nae-team/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nae-team/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_IN
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nae-team/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nae-team/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nae-team/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Fetched 306 kB in 16s (18.4 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/nae-team/ppa/ubuntu xenial                         Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/nae-team/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

The output from terminal after running `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` is:

```
hirak@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
[sudo] password for hirak: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
hirak@ubuntu:~$
```

What is the problem ? How to fix this ? Please help me... Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two things - First : the [`launchpad.net/nae-team`](https://launchpad.net/~nae-team/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) repository has no packages for Ubuntu 16.04.
That's the reason for the error message you get - to remove the PPA execute these commands :

```
sudo apt install ppa-purge  
sudo ppa-purge nae-team/ppa  
sudo apt update
```

Second : There were no updates for Ubuntu 16.04 released in the last days -> [Ubuntu Updates](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package_logs?utf8=%E2%9C%93&commit=Filter&head_only=true&noppa=1&vals=xenial&type=dists&levels%5Bbackports%5D=1&levels%5Bsecurity%5D=1&levels%5Bbase%5D=1&levels%5Bupdates%5D=1)
That is the simple reason why you did not receive updates for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS so many days.

The last update was [lxd (2.7-0ubuntu2~ubuntu16.04.1)](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-backports/lxd) from `backports` repo on 2016-12-28.
The first updates for Ubuntu 16.04 released after this date are from 2017-01-03 at 18.00 UTC.

**Update addressing your comment that you still get an error message** - proceed as follows.

Check for the PPA entries in the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` folder by running this command : `sudo ls -l /etc/apt/sources.list.d` and then delete every `nae-team` related`.list` file.
Delete each file by running : `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/<name-of-the-file>.list`

Also check the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file by running : `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`
Remove all existing entries of the PPA, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to close the file and <kbd>Y</kbd> to save these changes. Afterwards execute `sudo apt update` again, now it should work as expected.

Comment: The output of sudo ppa-purge nae-team/ppa is..               hirak@ubuntu:~$ sudo ppa-purge nae-team/ppa
Updating packages lists
AppStream cache update completed, but some metadata was ignored due to errors.
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/nae-team/ppa/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/nae-team/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Warning:  apt-get update failed for some reason

Comment: I am not aware of how to arrange the code. When I press enter, the comment is posted.

Comment: @Hirak : Please check the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and the  `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` folder - delete all entries and files of the PPA and then run `sudo apt update` afterwards again. :)

Comment: sorry but can you edit your answer and add this.. I am bit of a nerd when it comes to this.. Sorry...